# Update all Fields passed in object without using replace

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm writing a wrapper around certain functions of mongodb to enforce certain buisiness policies (such as having a last modified date, a document version &c). These extra fields will not appear in the model and will be irrelevant and transparent to the person implementing against this library. This library will be generic.

Therefore using `replaceOne` is out of the question.

What I would like is some way of passing all fields in a person passed object to the Update builder - so I can use .Set/.Inc accordingly to add the other fields.

An example to demonstrate what I want is below:

```
public static async Task UpdatePerson(string name, Person person)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("test");

        IMongoCollection<Person> collection = db.GetCollection<Person>("people");

        var query = Builders<Person>.Filter
        .Eq("name", name);

        var update = Builders<Person>.Update
        //Something here - how do I pass my person's properties?
        .Set("lastModified", DateTime.Now)
        .Inc("version",1);

        await collection.UpdateOneAsync(query, update );
    }

//--

//In real life this'll work for other types, this is for demonstration only
public class Person
    {
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string surname {get;set;}
}
```

So how can I go about this, without, for instance, looping through properties using Reflection?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I would like to "replace" the current document with the passed one, whilst retaining all fields not otherwise specified, and allowing myself to add additional fields as needed. In short, I would like to $set with all the properties of the passed object.

Comment: you think about something like an extension method in a form of `public static WithDefaultSetters(this UpdateBuilder self) { ... `? Where you automatically add your Set and Inc?

Comment: @ntohl - Unfortunately I haven't gotten that far. I haven't determined how to get an UpdateBuilder (or populate one automatically) from an object.

Comment: I mean there is nothing automatic in there. Whenever you start with `var update = Builders<T>.Update` you add `.WithDefaultSetters()` at the end. And I forgot it should be `public static void WithDefaultSetters<T>(this UpdateBuilder self)`

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a form of reflection. Unless you start tracking the deltas yourself.

Comment: @user2110845 how about the idea of redesigning your schema into something like: `{ _id: ..., lastModifiedDate: ..., entity: { .... } }` ? In that case you should be able to use $set to update the entity keeping other "metadata" fields unmodified

Comment: You can work with BsonDocument everywhere instead of working with defined classes, so you can change any field of that document before writing it, after reading it. You can convert any "normal" object (such as your Person class) into a BsonDocument using BsonExtensionMethods class' ToBsonDocument method. The other options is to have all your Person-like classes derive from a common class.

Comment: @user2110845 How about taking the superset of the existing document and the new set of changes and then using $set for the update. This way i don't feel the need of schema changes.

Comment: @SimonMourier - That could actually be part of a good solution. new BsonDocumentUpdateDefinition<T>(new BsonDocument("$set", bd)) should work if I have a BSONDocument that's been parsed using the extension method. Then I can add whatever I need to the rest. You should probably turn that comment into an answer, since this looks viable

Comment: Not sure I follow you :-) Here is what I had in mind: https://pastebin.com/raw/hhiwxGgA

Comment: @SimonMourier - Here's a tweaked version of your code which still lets me use UpdateDefinition so I can use Increment for instance.
https://pastebin.com/BYQit59x

Comment: Ok, here is a compiling code that seems to work (I've added a sub object just to see everything works as expected): https://pastebin.com/raw/HWLdjLkB

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are able to do this but the Mongodb Driver provides something called `[BsonExtraElements]`.

```
public class Person
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string surname {get;set;}
    [BsonExtraElements]
    public Dictionary<string,object> AdditionalFields { get; set; }
}
```

What will happen is that anything that cant be serialized to the model will be filled into that dictionary, no matter the type. You can add to it as well and remove.

This will add no additional overhead to your database, The only downside to this is that querying this dictionary is somewhat not a great experience as you may need to cast specific keys to their relevant expected types.

If this is not viable I suggest the BSON approach recommended by Simon.